# Is HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash() stateful?

Tags: c#, .net, hash

I need to compute hashes of multiple blocks of data independently. Something like this:

```
using( HashAlgorithm hasher = new ActualHashAlgorithm() ) {
    for( int i = 0; i = numberOfBlocks; i++ ) {
        byte[] block = getBlock( i );
        byte[] hash = hasher.ComputeHash( block );
        // use hash
    }
}
```

Can I reuse the same `HashAlgorithm` object between blocks? Will `HashAlgorithm` reset state between calls to `ComputeHash()` or do I need to dispose the `HashAlgorithm` object and create new one for each new block of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ComputeHash` is usually stateless although it depends on the actual implementation... you can check that at runtime by accessing `State` after the call to `ComputeHash`...

see

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformfinalblock.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.state.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Actually, when you need hash under .NET framework, I strongly recommended coding this function manually but not to use .NET framework.

Some months age, I immigrated a 32bit .NET program into 64bit windows. The program is crashed. At least I found hash value is different under different 32/64bit system, although same .NET program.
I used Djb algorithm instead of .NET hash algorithm, and the program run okay.

This document is about Djb hash algorithm, you can rewrite by C#. It is not a hard work.

- [DJB Hash Function](http://devnotes.wikispaces.com/DJB+Hash+Function)

Comment: I agree with you that using `object.GetHashCode()` shouldn't be used to create persistent hashes. However, utilizing the well documented hash algorithms in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace such as `SHA256` will not lead to the problems you warn of.